# wordpress vuejs boilerplate bootstrap install error

Tags: linux, wordpress, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I am new to vuejs and found a [wordpress boilerplate theme](https://github.com/EvanAgee/vuejs-wordpress-theme-starter) to start working off of, however I am unable to get things working correctly.

I am trying to include bootstrap-vue into the theme but I am receiving the following error when running 'npm run dev or build or watch' ---

```
    ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'charCodeAt' of undefined
    at module.exports (/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/vuejs-wordpress-theme-starter-master/node_modules/postcss-value-parser/lib/parse.js:17:22)
    at new ValueParser (/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/vuejs-wordpress-theme-starter-master/node_modules/postcss-value-parser/lib/index.js:7:22)
```

This is my second server and 4th attempt at trying to use bootstrap with the theme.

So far these are all my steps for creating a new server and trying to use the theme plus bootstrap ---

```
>          - Create server on Digital Ocean using wordpress marketplace image      
>            setup.    
>          - Set domain to server on DO
>          - Log in SSH and run setup script.
>          - Wait for propagation.
>          - Then do this - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04
>          - Change http to https in dashboard.
>          - Copied vue theme over to directory using SFTP.
>          - Install NPM with --- apt install npm
>          - CD into theme directory and run npm install
>          - Then run - npm run watch or npm run dev
>          - install node run --- curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
>          - then run -- sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
>          - cd into directory then npm install --save-dev cross-env
>          - then - npm audit fix
>          - then - npm install --save-dev css-loader@3.2.0
>          - then - npm install --save-dev webpack-cli@3.3.9
>          - then delete package.loc
>          - then - run npm install babel-preset-stage-2 --save-dev
>          - then - run npm install --dev 
>          postcss-loader 
>          postcss-import 
>          postcss-cssnext 
>          cssnano 
>          sugarss 
>          autoprefixer --save-dev
>          - then run install vue-loader (look up command)
>          - comment out webconfig - minimize true
>          - then run npm install --save-dev css-loader sass-loader node-sass extract-loader file-loader
>          - copied previous webconfig file
>          - navigate to folder then run npm install bootstrap
>          - add import in app.js -
>          - import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
>          - import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
>          - before initating vue, add -- Vue.use(BootstrapVue)`
           - then run - npm install vue --save
           - npm install vue
           - npm install vue-template-compiler
```

What am I doing wrong?

**[WEBPACK CONFIG](https://pastebin.com/jG0apEsE)**

Comment: if you're going to downvote my question then say why.

Comment: have you updated angular cli or node ??

Comment: but im not using angular and node is up to date

Comment: You can use VueJS without using the VueJS template. I do so! So first of all try VueJS inside wordpress using the CDN https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/ If you still want to try the theme, why don't you try running npm on your local computer instead of Digital Ocean?

Comment: thanks but i am going to use the vuejs theme and do it that way.

Comment: Got a similiar error some time ago, think it was about `npm install`ing on linux with a package.lock file generated on macos.
Solved it with something like `npm install sass-loader --force`/`npm install --force` 
Otherwise I would try to get it running with yarn, or using another version of npm

Comment: @dahe i tried your suggestion but its still not working unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first I would make sure all the loaders are loaded with your `package.json` file (I only see one of them in your steps):

**vue-style-loader** and **css-loader**

Second, in your ***webpack*** config, your module.rules should have this object:

```
{
  test: /\.css/,
  use: ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader'] // BOTH are needed!
}
```

And load it from the `App.vue`, under the  section, you should import:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css";
```

Finally, make sure you load the VueBootstrap before the Vue declaration, like:

```
...
import router from './router';

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  ...
```

**Update:**

Re-installing webpack sometimes solves the issue ([source](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/530)):

```
npm install --save-dev webpack
```

And/or:

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

If nothing of this helps, I would try using a simpler CSS rule, like:

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(s*)css$/,
        use: [
          'sass-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'style-loader'
        ]
      },
 ...
```

And see if it works. If it does, go step by step adding your current file and detect the exact point of failure (it could be the css-loader).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, im still running into the issue, I updated my question with the webpack config.

Comment: Yes finally I think I got it figured out! It seems to be working now, Thank you! Only thing is the loaders' order is important. So the style loader in `use` goes first, then css loader then sass loader.